# How to make background image to be fixed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using an image as a background, and it looks good until I use the keyboard, how to solve that?

[before the keyboard is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkTl0.png) and that's after the
[keyboard is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip3nW.png)

```
Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(
                    'images/joker.jpg',
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill)),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to Scaffold of this widget:

```
Scaffold(
   resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with `CupertinoPageScaffold` ?

Comment: Yes, you can add/change this property [source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageScaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html). @cahyo

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using The Stack widget, it uses the children[] widget.
but make sure to set the Image widget at the top of the list (so that the image can appears behind the form).

You can use this structure:

```
Stack( 
       children:[ 
                  Image(),    
                  SingleChildScrollView( 
                                        child: 
                                              YourFormWidgetHere()
                                        )
                 ]
       )
```